# BackboneJS Turbolinks History Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, turbolinks

I have a Rails 4 App that uses Turbolinks and Backbone.js.

Basically, my router looks like:

```
var BookRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
     '': 'index'
  },
  index: function(){
     var bookView = new BookView({
         el: ".wrapper"
     });
  }
});

$(function() {
   if (Backbone.History.started == false) {
     var bookRouter = new BookRouter();
     Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });
   }
});

$(document).on('page:load', function (){
   Backbone.history.stop();
   Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });
   var bookRouter = new BookRouter();
});
```

Here's the scenario:

1. A user lands on **`http://website.com/`**, which takes the user to the index route, which loads a template into the .wrapper, which is shown in my routing code above. This works fine.
2. A user clicks on one of my Rails generated pages (for example I have a **`http://website.com/books`** route which shows all the books that users have created.) This also works fine.
3. The user is still on the **`http://website/books`** route. If you click on my logo, it takes you to the index route (the one generated by the backbone code above). This works fine.
4. NOW THE PROBLEM: If you go back to Step 3, and instead of clicking the logo, decide to hit the back button, and go back from the books route to the index route, the contents that get put inside the $el .wrapper are repeated TWICE. So for example, in my template, I have the words "Please choose a book to continue". If you went to Step 1, you'd just see the words once. But now, you see n set of words each time you go to /books and then hit the back button n times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is the hack used to make Backbone.js play together with Turbolinks. I guess the source of this hack is [this blog post](http://www.goddamnyouryan.com/blog/rails-4-turbolinks-and-backbone) which recommends restarting the history whenever a link is handled by Turbolinks. However, stopping the history doesn't clear existing routes. So what you get after handling the `page:load` event is *two* router objects handling the same routes. And `Backbone.History` will trigger *every* callback for every matching route when you go back, even when they are registered for the same route - meaning that the `index` callback will run twice, hence the content duplication.

One way to deal with it would be simply removing the duplicate router:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function (){
   Backbone.history.stop();
   Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });
});
```

This is sufficient to trigger the router whenever Turbolinks is invoked. However, there seems to be a cleaner way to make `Backbone.History` trigger the router. From what I can tell from the source code, this should work correctly as well:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function (){
   Backbone.history.checkUrl();
});
```